# Suitability of paired t-test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

My intention is to determine that whether based on the sample of monthly observations of the returns of a strategy and an index, the mean population return of the two is statistically different. Is a paired t-test appropriate here?

Comment: A paired t-test is used when you have the same set of subjects being tested for a single metric before and after an intervention. Can you make this case for your problem?

Comment: I suppose not. I remember there was a statistical test that inspects the difference of the population mean of the two samples. I though it was this one

Comment: Then odds are a paired t-test would not be suitable.

Comment: z-test for difference in means is though

Comment: If you are comparing strategy_a to strategy_b in terms of their monthly returns, then yes you should be able to do this.